# Index of enum element in for-case pattern matching

Tags: swift, for-loop, enums, pattern-matching

How to get an index of iterated enum element in `for case let` pattern matching?

I have an enum:

```
enum EnumType {
    case A(associatedValue: Int)
    case B(associatedValue: String)
}
```

and array of enum elements:

```
let arrayOfEnums: [EnumType] = [.A(1), B("A"), .A(2), B("B")]
```

In `for` loop, where I iterate over only `A` elements, I want to get index of current iterated element in `arrayOfEnums` array:

```
for case let EnumType.A(associatedValue) in arrayOfEnums {
    // operations here
}
```

I known that I can get index from `Array.enumerated()`, but I don't know how to do this in `for case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
for case let (index, EnumType.A(associatedValue)) in arrayOfEnums.enumerated() {
    // operations here
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer, this worked for me too